# Things have been crazy busy meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning for this sentence "Things have been crazy busy" ?

Comment: What don't you understand? What do you think it means, if you had to guess?

Comment: @Catija I think crazy busy have diiferent meaning from very busy. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Crazy is just an intensifier in this case. The sentences mean the same, this one just implies that the level of "busy" is higher.

Comment: @Monirul: Be careful not to assume ***crazy*** is an acceptable substitute for ***very, extremely*** in all contexts. Many people (myself included) would see it as indicative of limited language skills in all but the most informal contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Crazy** literally means "mentally deranged," but in the slang sense it implies some combination of intensity, chaos, confusion and unbelievability --a level of sensory overload that could drive one crazy, or make you feel as if you were already mentally deranged.

Used as a modifier, it adds its own connotations to the adjective modified.

*Crazy busy* means intensely busy in a chaotic way.
*Crazy good* means unbelievably good.

This is considered informal speech and wouldn't be used in any formal context.